# The meaning of `empty` in gdb core dump

Tags: c++, gdb, coredump

When I use gdb to analyze some core dumps, I saw something like this:

```
#6  0x000055e01cf96326 in ClassOne::my_function (my_var=std::unique_ptr<ClassTwo> = {...}) at /usr/include/c++/10/bits/unique_ptr.h:173
my_object = std::shared_ptr<MyClass> (empty) = {get() = <optimized out>}
written = <optimized out>
```

Could anyone help to explain what the meaning of `(empty)` is here?

This word `empty` is too difficult to search and I have no idea what it means when I read the core dump. Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to show the relevant code (the function and the call to it)? Please try to create a [mre] to show us.

Comment: The shared pointer is empty/null though given this is optimised code you can't trust that this is actually the case